# Routing using different parameter not working on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Instead of using the default id parameter, i'm rerouting using `playerId`. Everything works as should, but when updating a player record, it routes back to the `id` instead of `playerId` and shows this error `undefined method`update' for nil:NilClass`.

**Routes**

```
resources :players, param: :playerId
```

**Controller**

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.update(player_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @player }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_player
      @player = Player.find_by(playerId: params[:playerId])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:playerId, :first_name, :last_name, :teamId,:image)
    end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :playerId %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :playerId %>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.label :teamId %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:teamId, Team.all, :teamId, :name, { :prompt => 'Team Select', :selected => @player.teamId }) %>
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
         root GET    /                                 pages#home
      players GET    /players(.:format)                players#index
              POST   /players(.:format)                players#create
   new_player GET    /players/new(.:format)            players#new
  edit_player GET    /players/:playerId/edit(.:format) players#edit
       player GET    /players/:playerId(.:format)      players#show
              PATCH  /players/:playerId(.:format)      players#update
              PUT    /players/:playerId(.:format)      players#update
              DELETE /players/:playerId(.:format)      players#destroy
```

Comment: for html or json?

Comment: for html @TimmyVonHeiss

Comment: add to question your form, please

Comment: Done. removed div's etc.

Comment: what does your rake routes list? Can you add the result to the question?

Comment: Added routes @ShabiniRajadas

Comment: Where is your `set_player` method called?

Comment: @omnikron it's set in the before action. before_action :set_player, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]